# Predicting point forecast using Random walk model coefficients

Tags: r, arima, random-walk

I have created a random walk model ARIMA(0,1,0) in R. The coefficients and R output is as shown below:

```
arima(x = Y, order = c(0, 1, 0), xreg = Indp_varbl)
Coefficients:
          t2       t3
      9.1993  18.0351
s.e.  0.4921   7.7715
```

I wanted to ask how I can forecast points using these coefficients through an equation? I have gone through papers but was not able to find exact equation using regressors as well:

```
Yt = Yt-1 + mean error
```

is generally used. How can I get the equation for the same?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y$ denote the dependent variable and $x_1$, $x_2$ denote the independent ones. Then

$$ \Delta y_t = 9.1993 x_{1,t} + 18.0351 x_{2,t} + u_t $$

For example, if you have values for $y_{t-1}$, $x_{1,t}$ and $x_{2,t}$, the point prediction of $y_t$ will be

$$ \hat y_t = y_{t-1} + 9.1993 x_{1,t} + 18.0351 x_{2,t} + 0 $$

(as $\hat u_t=0$).